# object references in LINQ to SQL are incorrectly saved or loaded

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, entityset

I tried to store and reload objects and their references between each other. The problem is when I reload the data from the database the references are not set correctly.

Here is an example code which describes the problem. I comment the the expcted state and the real state of the output in the code.

```
[Table(Name = "ClassA")]
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        LinksToClassB = new EntitySet<ClassB>();
    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Association]
    public EntitySet<ClassB> LinksToClassB { get; set; } //=> 1 to n cardinality

    [Association]
    public ClassB OneLinkToClassB { get; set; }//=> 1 to 1 cardinality
}


[Table(Name = "ClassB")]
public class ClassB
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseContext : DataContext
{
    public Table<ClassA> ClassATable;
    public Table<ClassB> ClassBTable;

    public DatabaseContext(string connection) : base(connection) { }
}



[TestClass]
public class Test
{
    string path = @"F:\Temp\Testspace - Forum Database\database.mdf";//path to database

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        //creates Database
        DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext(path);

        if (context.DatabaseExists())//Delete if exists
        {
            context.DeleteDatabase();
        }

        context.CreateDatabase();

        ClassB b1 = new ClassB(); b1.Name = "name 1";
        ClassB b2 = new ClassB(); b2.Name = "name 2";
        ClassB b3 = new ClassB(); b3.Name = "name 3";

        ClassA a = new ClassA();

        //now the references will be added to the object a

        //in 1-n references
        a.LinksToClassB.Add(b1);
        a.LinksToClassB.Add(b2);
        a.LinksToClassB.Add(b3);

        //and the has-one reference (OneLinkToClassB)
        a.OneLinkToClassB = b1;


        context.ClassATable.InsertOnSubmit(a);

        context.SubmitChanges(); //store in database


        //now the database will be reloaded
        context = new DatabaseContext(path);


        //Check if all ClassB objects were correctly stored and reloaded
        foreach (ClassB x in context.ClassBTable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.ID + "; " + x.Name);
            /*    
                -> expected output:
                    1; name 1
                    2; name 2
                    3; name 3
                -> real output
                    1; name 1
                    2; name 2
                    3; name 3

                -> check!
            */
        }

        //check if all ClassA objects were correctly stored and reloaded
        foreach (ClassA x in context.ClassATable)//context.ClassATable has only one entry
        {
            Console.WriteLine("check of entitys set");

            //check of 1-n references
            foreach (ClassB b in x.LinksToClassB)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.ID + " has a link to " + b.ID + ", " + b.Name);
                /*
                    -> expected output:
                        1 has a link to 1, name 1
                        1 has a link to 2, name 2
                        1 has a link to 3, name 3

                    -> real output
                        1 has a link to 1, name 1

                    -> doesn't match...
                */
            }


            Console.WriteLine("check of single link");

            //check of 1-1 reference
            Console.WriteLine(x.ID + " has a link to " + x.OneLinkToClassB.ID + ", " + x.OneLinkToClassB.Name);
            /*
                    -> expected output:
                        1 has a link to 1, name 1

                    -> real output
                        this line throws an NullReferenceException
            */
        }
    }
}
```

I hope anyone can give me a hint how to solve this bug in my code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Nick said the "parent / child association(s) are missing". Here now the complete changed code:

```
[Table(Name = "ClassA")]
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        LinksToClassB = new EntitySet<ClassB>();
    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    private int ID;

    [Association(ThisKey = "ID", OtherKey = "ClassAId")]
    private EntitySet<ClassB> LinksToClassB;//=> 1 to n cardinality

    public void addLink(ClassB x)
    {
        LinksToClassB.Add(x);
        x.setLink(this);
    }

    public HashSet<ClassB> getLinks()
    {
        HashSet<ClassB> collection = new HashSet<ClassB>();
        foreach(ClassB x in LinksToClassB)
        {
            collection.Add(x);
        }
        return collection;
    }
}


[Table(Name = "ClassB")]
public class ClassB
{
    private EntityRef<ClassA> _classA = default(EntityRef<ClassA>);

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    private int ClassAId { get; set; }

    [Association(ThisKey = "ClassAId", OtherKey = "ID", IsForeignKey = true)]
    private ClassA ClassA
    {
        get
        {
            return _classA.Entity;
        }
        set
        {
            _classA.Entity = value;
        }
    }

    private ClassA getLink()
    {
        return _classA.Entity;
    }

    public void setLink(ClassA x)
    {
        _classA.Entity = x;
    }
}

public class DatabaseContext : DataContext
{
    public Table<ClassA> ClassATable;
    public Table<ClassB> ClassBTable;

    public DatabaseContext(string connection) : base(connection) { }
}



[TestClass]
public class Test
{
    string path = @"F:\Temp\Testspace - Forum Database\database.mdf";//path to database

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        //creates Database
        DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext(path);

        if (context.DatabaseExists())//Delete if exists
        {
            context.DeleteDatabase();
        }

        context.CreateDatabase();

        ClassB b1 = new ClassB(); b1.Name = "name 1";
        ClassB b2 = new ClassB(); b2.Name = "name 2";
        ClassB b3 = new ClassB(); b3.Name = "name 3";

        ClassA a = new ClassA();

        //now the references will be added to the object a

        //in 1-n references
        a.addLink(b1);
        a.addLink(b2);
        a.addLink(b3);

        context.ClassATable.InsertOnSubmit(a);

        context.SubmitChanges(); //store in database


        //now the database will be reloaded
        context = new DatabaseContext(path);


        //Check if all ClassB objects were correctly stored and reloaded


        foreach (ClassB x in context.ClassBTable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.ID + "; " + x.Name);
            /*    
                -> expected output:
                    1; name 1
                    2; name 2
                    3; name 3
                -> real output
                    1; name 1
                    2; name 2
                    3; name 3

                -> check!
            */
        }

        //check if all ClassA objects were correctly stored and reloaded
        foreach (ClassA x in context.ClassATable)//context.ClassATable has only one entry
        {
            Console.WriteLine("check of entitys set");

            //check of 1-n references
            foreach (ClassB b in x.getLinks())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b.ID + " has a link to " + b.ID + ", " + b.Name);
                /*
                    -> expected output:
                        1 has a link to 1, name 1
                        1 has a link to 2, name 2
                        1 has a link to 3, name 3

                    -> real output
                        1 has a link to 1, name 1
                        1 has a link to 2, name 2
                        1 has a link to 3, name 3

                    -> check!
                */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless omitted, it looks like your parent / child association(s) are missing.

```
[Table(Name = "ClassA")]
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        LinksToClassB = new EntitySet<ClassB>();
    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Association(ThisKey="ID", OtherKey="ClassAId")]
    public EntitySet<ClassB> LinksToClassB { get; set; } //=> 1 to n cardinality

    [Association]
    public ClassB OneLinkToClassB { get; set; }//=> 1 to 1 cardinality
}


[Table(Name = "ClassB")]
public class ClassB
{
    private EntityRef<ClassA> _classA = default(EntityRef<ClassA>);

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public int ClassAId { get; set; }

    [Association(ThisKey = "ClassAId", OtherKey = "ID", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public ClassA ClassA {
        get
        {
            return _classA.Entity;
        }
        set {
            // property changed implementation omitted for brevity...
            _classA.Entity = value;
        } 
    }
}
```